# Converter String vazia para inteiro para inserir na base de dados

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, netbeans

Como posso fazer a conversão de um campo de texto (JTextField por exemplo) vazio, para inteiro, para posteriormente inserir na base de dados?

Tenho na base de dados campos definidos como int, mas quando o utilizador não preenche um jTextField fica uma String vazia que não é aceite na base de dados. Como posso resolver este problema ?

Uso NetBeans 8.0.1

**Atualização:**

```
Integer numOfContas = StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(jFormattedNIFOfContas.getText().trim()) ? null : Integer.parseInt(jFormattedNIFOfContas.getText().trim());
        System.out.println("Nif Of Contas: " + numOfContas);
```

A variável numOfContas já fica com null, mas é interpretada como String porque dá o seguinte erro:

```
Nif Of Contas: null
468
Dados não inseridos!!
nov 17, 2014 11:31:24 AM faturacao.ConfEmpresa jButtonRegistarActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column 'NIF_Of_Contas' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1618)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1549)
    at faturacao.ConfEmpresa.jButtonRegistarActionPerformed(ConfEmpresa.java:3050)
    at faturacao.ConfEmpresa.access$6300(ConfEmpresa.java:44)
    at faturacao.ConfEmpresa$62.actionPerformed(ConfEmpresa.java:1749)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar essa sintaxe:

```
int numero = StringUtils.isNotBlank(minhaString) ? Integer.parseInt(minhaString) : 0;
```

Assim, o `parseInt` é usado somente se a `minhaString` não for vazia.

Teoricamente, conforme dito nos comments, esta sintaxe deveria funcionar no NetBeans:

```
int numero = StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(minhaString) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(minhaString);
```

Se quiser `null`, use o *wrapper* Integer:

```
Integer numero = StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(minhaString) ? null : Integer.parseInt(minhaString);
```

Também, conforme os comments, pode ser necessário um `if` para diferenciar o `null` de zero ao inserir no DB:

```
int numero;
boolean flagNulo;

if( isNullOrEmpty(minhaString) ) {
   numero = 0;
   flagNulo = true;
} else {
   numero = Integer.parseInt(minhaString);
   flagNulo = false;
}
```

E na hora de inserir no DB, teste a *flag*.

Comment: Não estou a conseguir :s de qualquer forma obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @HugoMachado dei uma bela atualizada na resposta, de uma espiada. E avise onde está tendo problema, que tento melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Lembre-se que `int` nao vai funcionar com null, mas `Integer` diferencia null de zero.

Comment: Utilizei o wrapper para me dar null, e fiz um print para a consola e o valor de facto já fica null, de qualquer das formas, dá-me o erro:
Nif Of Contas: null
455
Dados não inseridos!!
nov 17, 2014 10:11:32 AM faturacao.ConfEmpresa jButtonRegistarActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column 'NIF_Of_Contas' at row 1

Comment: Entao, nesse caso você usa o terceiro exemplo que eu dei, e na hora do INSERT usa a flag para montar a query ou com o valor numérico, ou com a palavra null mesmo. Se puder, acrescente no final da pergunta (editando-a) a parte do insert. A impressão que dá é que ou você está usando a interface errada do banco, ou o campo não está dando suporte.

Answer (score 0):

Usa um `if`:

```
    int valor;
    if (JTextField.getText().equals("")){
        valor=0;
    }else {
       valor=Integer.parseInt(JTextField.getText());
       //aqui até devias de verificar se por acaso o texto não contem nenhum texto, 
       //porque se o utilizador se enganar será lançada uma excepção 
}
```

Comment: Mas na BD é diferente ser 0 ou ser null. Esse valor = 0 vai colocar o 0 na BD e não o null certo ?

Comment: e qual a logica de guardar null e não 0? o null pode te vir a trazer problemas

Comment: Imaginemos que tenho um campo para introduzir um valor que no caso tem de ser 0. Se o campo não for de preenchimento obrigatorio, se não o preencher vai introduzir o valor 0 e não indicar que o campo não foi preenchido (null na BD )

Comment: e se inserires o -1, para campos que nao foram preenchidos? nao sei se é possivel, mas acho que sempre era melhor do que deixar completamente vazio

Comment: Será uma solução mandar o -1, mas para já o que me pedem é para tentar não introduzir outros valores, isto é, se não é preenchido na bd tem de aparecer null